# Angular v12 - Unit Test - [ERROR] No specs found

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

After developing my Angular application I would like to run unit tests with Karma and Jasmine.

I haven't written any unit-tests yet, but trying to run the default ones, with the 'ng test' command, **I notice that the .spec files are not recognized by Karma-Jasmine**.

Inside the browser, Karma gives the following message: "**Incomplete, no specs found**", in the terminal "**Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS**".

I tried to generate a new application with the Angular CLI and to run the unit test. And it works.

Within my application, the **Karma configuration files have not been touched**, they are the same as those of the test application, and I don't understand why the .spec files are not recognized.

angular.json

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "dibfibo": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/dibfibo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "dibfibo:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "dibfibo:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "dibfibo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "dibfibo"
}
```

karma.conf.js

```js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
        // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
        // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
        // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/dibfibo'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' }
      ]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you add your angular.json file? There maybe some info regarding why it is happening. Also add karma.js file too, we can see if there's an issue

Comment: I edit post, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that no tests were found in my project after upgrading my Angular version from v11 to v12.

In my `tests.ts` file I had this:

```js
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

Works now after changing to this:

```js
const context = require.context('src/', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```